# How to get the best performance of repeated function every x seconds

Tags: java, performance, time, time-complexity

I have a test application that creates a random code every 20 seconds.

My question simply is what's the best way to do a function that repeats itself every `x seconds` with best performance (The question is mainly for `Java` but it's not necessary)

this is the code that I'm currently using but I'm not sure it's the best:

```
void generate() throws InterruptedException {
    createNewCode();
    Thread.sleep(2000); // wait for 2 seconds
    generate();
}
```

Comment: This code will generate a StackOverFlow error if it will run for enough time (infinite recursion).

Comment: What do you mean with "best performance"? When you only run it every 2 seconds, performance does not really matter

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html